# How to adjust Recycleview retrive on if else condition using multiple view Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have multiple view adapter for my Java android app

I am using this code to switch views in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
if (viewType == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item,parent,false);
            ViewHolderOne holderOne = new ViewHolderOne(view);
            return holderOne;
        } else{
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trend_item,parent,false);
            ViewHolderTwo holderTwo = new ViewHolderTwo(view);
            return holderTwo;

        }
```

This is `getItemType` code

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return position % 3;
    }
```

Now on my `Fragment`, I am showing the above two different layouts on a single `Recycleview`, how do I specify on my Fragment that if  `viewType = 1`, then this is how I want to retrieve data from the database into that layout because now since i am using one `Recycleview` to populate data from the Adapter above, it uses same logic, i want to change the content that shows in the second layout switch from `postadapter`

Comment: share your code

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Share code that not working or what you have tried at least. don't need a working code snippet here. also need more clarity about your question what you trying to accomplish and what you getting.